# Getting an error when inserting data into Realtime Database from Flutter App

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have done the required setup for Firebase connectivity on my Flutter app and when I tried to insert user input data into Realtime Database
Code

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("tododb");

createTask(String title, String date) {
  String id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
  ref.child(id).set(
    {
      "itemTitle": title,
      "date": date,
      "id": id,
    },
  ).then((value) {
    debugPrint("Done");
  }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
    debugPrint("An error occured");
  });
}
```

When called this function i am getting this error.

> Local module descriptor class for
> com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
> I/DynamiteModule( 5986): Considering local module
> com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module
> com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
> W/ProviderInstaller( 5986): Failed to load providerinstaller module:
> No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite
> found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
> W/ManagedChannelImpl( 5986): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
> W/Firestore( 5986): (24.7.0) [WriteStream]: (3a2461f) Stream closed
> with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve
> host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
> "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname

I tried searching on internet but nothing worked

Comment: The error message seems to come from Cloud Firestore, not from Realtime Database, which the code you shared in the question uses. How do you initialize Firebase in your app?